# is Android Maps API key! unique for each project?

Tags: android

I am new to android programming and trying to build a map activity app.
I tried to get the Android Maps API key!. My question is. is Android Maps API key! unique for each project? or else is it unique for each developer.
Is it possible to use the same Android Maps API key! more than one different aps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same Key can be used in any number of Apps. If you remember that while generating the API key, it must have asked you about your google account username and password. So, that API key is valid for all the apps signed with the same signature.

Answer (score 1):

Are you actually asking about Google Maps for Android API? The key that is issued for using the API is tied to the certificate that was submitted when the key was requested. Therefore, for every app signed with that certificate, the API key issued for that certificate will work. That could be any number of apps.